# Select node without namespace with XPath

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces

I have a xml like

```
<root xmlns:ns1="http://foo">
    <ns1:child1>Text</ns1:child1>
    <ns1:child2>Number</ns1:child2>
</root>
```

Now I get this from different persons, so that for example person 2 sends me another message with the same structure like

```
<root xmlns:anotherNs="http://foo">
    <anotherNs:child1>Another Text</anotherNs:child1>
    <anotherNs:child2>Another Number</anotherNs:child2>
</root>
```

So the only difference is the name of the namespace. How can I select the content of child2 for both xml's with one XPath expression?

Something like "/root/child2" or "//child2" did not work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`local-name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-local-name) function like so:

```
//*[local-name()='child2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind any prefix you like (say banana) to the namespace `"http://foo"`, and the expression `/root/banana:child2` will find the child2 element, regardless what namespace prefix has been used in the source document. Only the namespace URI has to match.